# python is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: python

I save as a file `myexamply.py`, but when I run it in command section

```
desktop\>python myexample.py
```

the result should be "hello world" but instead it is showing

> python is not recognized as internal or external command

My code:

```py
print("hello world")
```

Comment: Refer ->   https://www.educative.io/edpresso/err-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: It appears you have not installed Python. It may be that the text you are following expects Python to be installed already. On  Linux distros it often is. But not on Windows. Download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed python? Is python in your path? Did you try to use:

```
python3 myexample.py
```